# Powershell; foreach-object; How to create proper output again to pipeline

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have already searched quite a bit to find a satisfying answer to this but could not find it (neither here on SO nor via Google).

I am currently using the following command to get the Name and the Product Version out of all Printer Drivers on a print Server  and pipe it to the pipeline:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PrinterDriver | select name, driverpath | %{ $Name = $_.name; $version = (get-item -LiteralPath $_.driverpath).VersionInfo.ProductVersion; write-output ($Name, $Version) }
```

Technically, this works but the piped Output is ugly. The Output Looks like this:

> Remote Desktop Easy Print,3,Windows x64
>   6.1.7601.17514
>   PCL6 Driver for Universal Print,3,Windows x64
>   3.4.100.1
>   MS Publisher Color Printer,3,Windows x64
>   6.1.7600.16385

What I want to achieve is something like the following (like the Standard Output of objects which are not piped through the foreach-object) - eg. from the following command:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PrinterDriver | select name, driverpath
```

The Output of the above command Looks like this:

```
name                                                        driverpath
----                                                        ----------

Remote Desktop Easy Print,3,Windows x64                     C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\mxdwdrv.dll
PCL6 Driver for Universal Print,3,Windows x64               C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\ricu00gr.dll
```

**Question:**
How can I prepare the Output within a foreach-object to resemble the above formatting / object piping?

Thanks for any Input.

With Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a pscustomobject into a foreach loop like this :

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PrinterDriver | %{
    [pscustomobject]@{
    Name=$_.Name
    Driverpath=$_.Driverpath
    Version=(Get-Item $_.Driverpath).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Technically, this is the direct answer to my question (how to create proper Output to pipeline from inside a foreach.object loop. 

The answer from Vincent K was the exact match to solve the Problem I had in a very elegant manner.

But because your answer Matches the question, I give you the "accepted answer flag".

Answer (score 5):

Create Custom property using Select-Object cmdlet.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PrinterDriver | select Name,Driverpath,@{l='Version';ex={(get-item -LiteralPath $_.driverpath).VersionInfo.ProductVersion}}
```

Comment: Great answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for such a fast Reply.